# Signature of a function

Tags: c++

i am a beginner level programmer and have just started learning programming in C++,

i had a look at a feature called "FUNCTION OVERLOADING" and while i have understood the purpose and implementation at the code level, i haven't understood how it is implemented at the compiler level that is how does a compiler differentiates between the signature of the different functions with same name and would

```
return-type func-name (data-type 1 , data-type-2);
```

would have the same signature as

```
return-type func-name (data-type 2 , data-type-1);
```

and does the same thing applies to overloaded constructors too ?

Comment: You may accept the best answer below,it's the rule on this site.^_^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler uses a technique known as [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Briefly, the compiler encodes the number and type of the arguments into the actual name written into the object file.  There are a few examples in the Wikipedia article on the subject, including examples from C++.

As a specific example, I've used g++ on a Mac to compile the following C++ file:

#### test.cpp

```
int f(int x) {}

int f(double x, char y) {}
```

with

```
g++ -S test.cpp
```

This results in the assembly language file (elided somewhat):

#### test.s

```
.globl __Z1fi
__Z1fi:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    leave
    ret
.globl __Z1fdc
__Z1fdc:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movsd   %xmm0, -8(%rbp)
    movb    %dil, -12(%rbp)
    leave
    ret
```

The important part here is that the functions are called `__Z1fi` and `__Z1fdc` in the assembly language output, which the linker will see.  You can probably infer that `f` is the name of the function, and for arguments, we have `i` (int) and `dc` (double and char). Note that order of arguments is encoded too!

Now consider what would happen if you had

```
int f(int x) {}
int f(int y) {}
```

This is of course not an acceptable situation as far as the language is concerned, since a call like `f(10)` could not be resolved. Theoretically a language could specify that the second declaration replaces the first, but C++ does not do this.  This is simply an illegal overloading.

It turns out that name mangling actually shows why this should be an error.  The compiler would try to make two distinct functions with the name `__Z1fi` (the actual name is not defined by the language but is compiler dependent).  We can't have two identically named functions in a program at this level.

Comment: @ArunKumar - accept the answer if you agree that it has answered the question. That is the way to go on SO.